# How do I override file.write() in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below works on Python 2.6 but not on Python 3.x:

```
old_file_write = file.write 

class file():
    def write(self, d):
        if isinstance(d, types.bytes):
            self.buffer.write(d)
        else:
            old_file_write(d)

# ... some code I cannot change or do not want to change
f = open("x")
f.write("...")
f.write(b"...")
sys.stdout.write(b"...")
sys.stdout.write("...")
print(b"...")
print("...")
```

The problem is that in Python 3.x the first line will generate an error:

```
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

How can I make this work in Python 3.x?

In fact, two years later, I'm still looking for a solution that will work on both versions (2.5+, and 3.x).

For those who are still wondering why I am looking for this, it is just in order to be able to make old code (others code, which sometimes you cannot modify) to work with newer versions of python.

This is not about my code, it's about how can you write some code that plays nicely with bad code :)

Comment: What is the "file" object?  Please provide more code.

Comment: Please elaborate. Is `file` a file object? Is `file.write` a function object that you are assigning to `old_file_write`, or are you trying to write something to `file` and store the number of bytes written in `old_file_write`?

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea: Confusing strings and bytes will cause you no end of problems. You cannot simply treat strings and bytes as if they are the same thing. They're not the same thing. What you're doing cannot be made to work in a simple way. Strings are encoded into bytes. They're separate things. If your application is broken, fix it to properly encode and decode strings. – S.Lott 0 secs ago edit

Comment: @S.Lott: I do agree with but there are cases where you cannot do this. Also I need to overwrite the file.write() for a good purpose: to hack Python to output Unicode strings as UTF-8 with one exception: when the output is console (tty) on Windows, case where I need to do some additional hacks in order to output the string as Unicode (yes it is possible but not how people may expect).

Still this question is about overriding python methods to change their behavior - one can use this method in good or bad way.

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea: The question is barely about "overriding python methods".  It's about two things. (1) bad polymorphism via type identification and (2) writing a method that magically works for bytes as well as Unicode.  You have to use Unicode.  Using "bytes" means your programs are broken and need to be fixed.  You don't need any of this if you simply use Unicode characters like you're supposed to.

Comment: @S.Lott: Have you considered that he may have to deal with both bytes and text provided by an external source? It may not be up to him. Though, if it is up to him, I do agree that he probably shouldn't be mixing text and byte input.

Comment: @JAB: Yes.  And that means he needs to fix this at the interface.  Not down inside an extended implementation of `file`.

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems.

1: Your `file` class isn't inheriting from any specific class. If I've interpreted the situation correctly, it should be a subclass of `io.TextIOWrapper`.

2: In both Python 2.6 and 3.x, the `types` module (which would need to be imported in the first place) has no element `bytes`. The recommended method is to just use `bytes` on its own.

Redone snippet:

```
import io, sys

class file(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def write(self, d, encoding=sys.getdefaultencoding()):
        if isinstance(d, bytes):
            d = d.decode(encoding)
        super().write(d)

old_stdout = sys.stdout    # In case you want to switch back to it again

sys.stdout = file(open(output_file_path, 'w').detach())  # You could also use 'a', 'a+', 'w+', 'r+', etc.
```

Now it should do what you want it to, using `sys.stdout.write` to the output file that you specify. (If you don't wish to write to a file on disk but instead wish to write to the default `sys.stdout` buffer, using `sys.stdout = file(sys.stdout.detach())` would probably work.)

Do note that, since Python 3.x does not have the `file` class, but 2.6 does have the `io` module, you will have to use one of the classes of the `io` module. My above code is just an example, and if you want it to be more flexible you'll have to work that out on your own. That is, depending on what sort of file you're writing to/what mode you're writing to in, you'll probably want to use a different class in `io`.

Comment: I updated the example, it seams that this does not work for the sys.stdout.write but works with print.

Comment: You want to override `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: Exactly, in fact I would like to overwrite any file.write (I suppose sys.stdout.write is just the same file.write).

Comment: I updated my answer to involve assigning a file object to `sys.stdout`. That should do what you want.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a little note if you don't want to write to a file on disk but instead want to write to sys.stdout.

Answer (score 0):

```
old_file_write = file.write
```

You're using the class-level method of the `file` class.

```
old_file_write(d)
```

Should never have worked.  I believe you're still copying and pasting incorrectly.

I think you may have had

```
old_file_write(self,d)
```

Which might have worked.

Your approach is not very good.  Think about this instead.

```
class MyKindOfFile( file ):
    def write(self, d):
        if isinstance(d, types.bytes):
            self.buffer.write(d)
        else:
            super( MyFindOfFile, write )(d)
```

This will work out a LOT better for you, since it uses simple inheritance in a more typical way.

Comment: The entire idea is that I want to replace the file.write() python function with mine, that does accept `bytes`. I added some usage examples to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`file` objects can write bytes, but you need to open the file **in the correct mode**

```
fp = open('file.bin', 'wb') # open in binary mode
fp.write(b"some bytes") 
pf.close()
```

If you want to write strings to the disk you need to encode them first.

Comment: I fully understand the difference between str and bytes but you should be aware that there are cases where you may want to write both str (Unicode) and bytes to a file, the main reason being to keep the code easy to read, the "improved" write() will know how to encode the str properly.