# Overriding file.write in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm aware of the SO post [How do I override file.write() in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046066/how-do-i-override-file-write-in-python-3) but after looking it over and trying whats suggested I'm still stuck.

I want to override the file.write method in Python 3 so that I can "REDACT" certain words (Usernames, Passwords...etc).

I found a great example of overriding the print and general stdout and stderr http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119404/

The issue is that it doesn't work for file.write. How can I override the file.write?

My code for redacting when printing is:

```
   def write(self, text):
        for word in self.redacted_list:
            text = text.replace(word, "REDACTED")
        self.origOut.write(text)
        return text
```

thanks

Comment: I mean, your welcome to overwrite the built-in `write()` function, but why not make some sort of "safe-write" function, or even a class that provides the functionality you want?

Comment: You can't set the attributes of built-in types so you should create your own class instead that provides the corresponding functionality. You can still set `__builtins__.open = custom_open` (at least for CPython).

Answer (score 0):

From the `self.origOut.write(text)` I assume you are trying to write an in-between-class that pretends to be a file but provides a different `.write()` method.
I don't see any problems in the code you posted (assuming it's a method of a class you use). Possibly you wrote a class but forgot to create instances of it?
Did you try to write something like this?:

```
class IAmNoARealFile:
    def __init__(self, real_file):
        self.origOut = real_file

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):  # provide everything a file has
        return getattr(self.origOut, attr_name)

    def write(self, ...):
        ...


with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f = IAmNotARealFile(f)  # did you forget this?
    f.write('some text SECRET blah SECRET')  # calls IAMNotARealFile.write with your extra code

with open('test.txt') as f:
    f = IAmNotARealFile(f)
    print(f.read())  # this "falls through" to the actual file object
```

you will also probably want to `return self.origOut.write()` in your own `.write()`, if you don't have a specific reason not to.

Note that if you rewrite `open()` to directly return `IAMNotARealFile`:

```
def open(*args, **kwargs):
    return IAMNotARealFile(open(*args, **kwargs))
```

you will have to manually supply (some) "magic methods" because

> This method may still be bypassed when looking up special methods as the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in functions. See Special method lookup.

--docs for [`.__getattribute__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), but it also applies to `.__getattr__()`

Why?

> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods **(the special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be consistently invoked by the interpreter)**.

-- On [special ("magic") method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) [code style and emphasis mine]